# How can I change my array sorting to like that

Tags: php, arrays, reorganize

This is my array which I get on my database:

> Array  (
>
> ```
>  [0] => Array 
>     ( 
>         [ID] => 4 
>         [USERNAME] => John
>     ) 
>
> [1] => Array 
>     ( 
>         [ID] => 7 
>         [USERNAME] => Ted 
>     )
> ```
>
> )

But I want to like this:

```
Array 
( 
   [4] => John 
   [7] => Ted 
)
```

I tried to do like I want by using `array_merge`, `array_push` etc. But I couldn't.

Comment: Where are the values "Selim" and "Hakan" supposed to come from?

Comment: Sorry i've written wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a simple `foreach`.

```
$users = array();

foreach ($results as $user) {
  $users[$user['ID']] = $user['USERNAME'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in function for this, just write a simple loop:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $e) {
    $new_array[$e['ID']] = $e['USERNAME'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP >= 5.5 you can do this:

```
$newArray = array_combine(
    array_column($oldArray, 'ID'),
    array_column($oldArray, 'USERNAME')
);
```

**EDIT**

For earlier versions of PHP, a simple equivalent is

```
$newArray = array_combine(
    array_map(function($value) { return $value['ID']; }, $oldArray ),
    array_map(function($value) { return $value['USERNAME']; }, $oldArray )
);
```